# Decompile jpa entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

try to fix one issue in our old spring application. Unfortunately source was lost and I have difficulty to decompile jpa entity. The class is decompiled sucessfuly but there is only basic anotation as @Entity, @Table. There is completety missing links and column names between entity classes (@OnToMany, @Column, etc). I have tried decompiler cfr, d4j, procyon but without sucess.

Does anybody know if it is possible and what kind of decompiler is able to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One I use is http://jd.benow.ca/
Maybe all metadata isn't specified in annotations? if in XML then a decompiler clearly won't give that.

Comment: that is exactly what I need. There were couple of syntax errors, but it keep all anotation and after execution it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If decompilation gives you just partial results it could be that some annotations are not targeting runtime. 
This should however not be the case for any hibernate annotations.

One possibility could be to create a new spring test app, include your jar and launch a component scan on @entity, @mappedsuperclass and @embeddable. You would have to process the classes after yourself using reflection but at least you should be able to get everything out of it.

Should be some work though. Make an opensource project out of it after ;)